# passing value to javascript

Tags: javascript

hello please help me out regarding this dunction 
 i want to  pass value from the textbox to javascript function and over there i want to store it for other text box . here is the sample code '

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRowToTable(<?php echo $data['pno'];?>);" />
```

here is the javascript function

```
function addRowToTable(var a)
{
  ........................
.......................

  b.type = 'text';
  b.value ='over here how can i get this value of a ';  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try changing your function head from `function addRowToTable(var a)` -> `function addRowToTable(a)`, does a contain now your value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` : [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Answer (score 2):

**IF** your value for `$data['pno']` is a string, and not a number type, you need to do 
this :

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRowToTable('<?php echo $data['pno'];?>');" />
```

because you are still passing the value to `addRowToTable` as a string literal.

Also, what Nick Weaver said--nix the `var` in the function signature.

Comment: Thanks .It is no . so what else i need to do

Answer (score 2):

Let `json_encode()` take care about turning your variable in a JavaScript-compatible string:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable('<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data['pno'])); ?>');" />
```

PS: If you are using XHTML it's `onclick`, not `onClick`.